# Python -- divisibility and count

Tags: python, python-3.3

Okay, editing for clarity, sorry about the confusion.

I need to count the number of occurrences of a number (we'll say 2) between 1 and n (user inputted positive number). That includes each time given number can go into each number between 1 and n.

So every instance of 2 in each number up to n. so 10 would be 5 in ten, plus 4 in 9, 4 in 8, 3 in 7, 3 in 6, 2 in 5, 2 in 4, 1 in 3, and 1 in 2. Remainders don't matter, I just need to count the 2s.

so a user inputting 10 should print 25, if my math is right.

I'm new and totally clueless.

As of right now, I basically have asking the user to input a number.

n = int (input("Enter a positive number between 1 and 1000"))

I had successfully gotten my code to divide by nine, but that isn't really what I'm trying to do. I think I need to convert everything between 1 and n to a string? Would that use a range like so 1:n? Is that even possible?

Then I could count how many of a certain number?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your textbook say?

Comment: What have you already tried? And if this is a a homework assignment, you should mention it.

Comment: I dont even understand what your asking ... ive read it a bunch of times too ...  ... how do you get 25 from 10?

Comment: I think I get it -- waiting for response from OP.

Comment: Okay, I edited it and hopefully it's clearer, hard to explain what I barely understand. It's just a practice problem, so any help is appreciated but explanations would be great. Joran, it would print 25 because that's how many 2s are in each number up to ten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something along these lines?

```
def count(n):
    occurrences = 0
    for i in range(n, 0, -1):  # i -> n, n-1, n-2, ... 3, 2, 1
        occurrences += i//2    # add whole number of 2's in this value of i
    return occurrences

print(count(10))  # 25
print(count(9))   # 20
```

If what that does is correct, it can be optimized and shorted to just:

```
def count(n):
    return sum(i//2 for i in range(n, 0, -1))
```

Which applies the built-in[`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#sum)function to a[`generator expression`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=expression#generator-expressions).

The`range(n, 0, -1)`is an [iterator](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html?highlight=iterator#iterators) that produces all the numbers from`n`to`1`backwards -- which I used since that's how you described what you wanted. Since doing it in that order doesn't really matter, it would probably be better (simpler) to just use`range(1, n+1)`which produces the sequence in ascending order (`1, 2, 3, ... n-2, n-1, n`).

Comment: Since OP is new to Python, it might help to explain what the code does.

Comment: could you explain the return line? I tweaked this so that it would print (count(n)) and it seems to work. Still testing but would love to understand the code.

Comment: @user3259535: Sure -- wasn't going to bother until I had confirmation of my interpretation.